# Form is not getting refreshed after I do (ngSubmit) in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

Below is snippet of `app.component.html`

```html
<form *ngIf="addForm" [formGroup]="addForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
```

In `app.component.ts`

```js
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.addForm.value);
  this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
      alert('Contract created successfully');
    });
}
```

My problem is after I get the alert, the form values should automatically get cleared i.e. the form should be refreshed. It's not happening for me. Any suggestion is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do clear form after alert ok click

Here's an example

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.addForm.value);
  this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
       if (!alert("Contract created successfully")) {
          this.addForm.reset();
       }

    });
}
```

You can also use `window.confirm`

```
onSubmit() {
      this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
        .subscribe(data => {
           if ( window.confirm('Contract created successfully') ) {
               //clicked Yes
               this.addForm.reset();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: glad to help you :)) please vote up and approve the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `reset()` method of the form.

```
onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.addForm.value);
  this.contractService.saveContract(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
      alert('Contract created successfully');
      // Reset Form      
      this.addForm.reset();
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried with this way, but my values are getting cleared before I click 'OK' of alert box. Is this the correct way, or it should clear when the alert pop-up gets closed.